# Which 'cacerts' should be used for updating Java Security File?

Tags: java, linux, file, certificate

I am about to update/add a Java certificate to the list of certificates in MacOS.

In order to know which 'cacerts' file to add to - ran this command:

`sudo find / -iname "*cacerts*" 2> /dev/null`

This is a result:

```
/Applications/DataGrip.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
/Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/Resources/zcacert.pem
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/excon-0.54.0/data/cacert.pem
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.7/lib/cacerts.pem
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/cacert.pem
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/cacert1024.pem
/opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
/opt/chefdk/LICENSES/cacerts-README.md
/opt/vagrant/embedded/cacert.pem
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/cacert.pem
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/cacert1024.pem
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/test/pycacert.pem
/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
/Users/user1/java/certificates/add_capitalone_cacert.sh
/Users/user1/java/certificates/cacerts
/Users/user1/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.1/tasks/cacerts
/Users/user1/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.2/tasks/cacerts
/Users/user1/Library/VirtualBox/vbox-ssl-cacertificate.crt
```

How to know which one I should add to? 
(I am using InteliJ IDE for development but not sure if that path `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/...` should be used to store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple test class in your Intellij IDE to print out which version it is using. Use this to print the path...

> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which JDK/JRE Intellij is using. The cacerts file is usually under JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security. We update this store for internally signed certs.